# Repeated XOR decryption

Tags: xor

I have this message in Hex:

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

I have no idea how to decrypt this.

How would I go about decrypting it. I'm a novice.
thank you

Comment: If that is all the information you have, likely you can't decrypt it. Do you have any additional information? For example, in the title you mention repeated xor. Do you know for a fact that the encryption method was repeated xor with some small key?

Comment: Are you the same person that asked [this](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/20057/repeated-xor-help)? If so, you should merge your accounts.

Comment: @mikeazo I see a lot of these things happening; there are a lot of crypto classes out there and thus a lot of identical questions are raised. If there are two IP's found that point to the same *residential house* then it could be the same person.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that this is not very difficult to solve. It also looks like this is part of a public cryptography challenge, so rather than giving it all away, I'll just provide you with a couple of pointers.

First take a look at this:

[image: screenshot of hexdump utility]

There is a clear repeating pattern every 5 bytes. This suggests two things: (i) an XOR key with a length of 5 was used here, and (ii) the original data is rather non-random (probably ASCII text). Try to find XOR key values that maximize the number of alphabet characters and spaces while minimizing the appearance of other characters. With a little bit of programming, you can get the computer to do this for you, and the answer should drop straight out.

(Alternatively, you might find a crib would be useful. If you know where this message came from, then I expect you can think of several words that it might contain.)